# Python balancing items in a list/numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have an array of tokens, and each token corresponds to a different class from `1` to `n`. I need to *balance* the `tokens` array/list so that there are an equal number of tokens for each class. I want to do this by removing the elements of `tokens`.

In the example below the class with the lowest number of tokens is `class 2`  which has only `2` tokens. So I want to remove elements from other classes until their count is also `2`.

e.g.

```
tokens  = array(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','l'])

classes = array([ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3])
```

In this example, the classes are listed in ascending order (for clarity of task) but in reality, the classes are in no particular order.

e.g.

```
sol = array(['c','d','e','f','g','h'])
```

*or*

```
sol = array(['a','b','e','f','g','h'])
```

*etc.*

Obviously because you have a choice of elements to remove in an excess class, you can have different solutions (like above). I need a function that can take the `tokens` and `classes` and output a `sol`.

Comment: Do you want to get one random solution or a deterministic one?

Comment: Unless this is the one and only instance you will ever touch python i suggest you try solving it yourself first, otherwise you will learn very little if anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do that with NumPy. This will always select the firs appearances of each class.

```
import numpy as np

def balance(tokens, classes):
    # Count appearances of each class
    c = np.bincount(classes - 1)
    n = c.min()
    # Accumulated counts for each class shifted one position
    cs = np.roll(np.cumsum(c), 1)
    cs[0] = 0
    # Compute appearance index for each class
    i = np.arange(len(classes)) - cs[classes - 1]
    # Mask excessive appearances
    m = i < n
    # Return corresponding tokens
    return tokens[m]

tokens  = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'l'])
classes = np.array([  1,   1,   1,   1,   2,   2,   3,   3,   3])
print(balance(tokens, classes))
# ['a' 'b' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h']
```

As it stands, the function returns an empty array when some class is completely missing (as the minimum number of appearances would be zero, so not class would appear in the solution), but you can adapt that if needed.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `Counter`:

```
tokens = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','l']
lst    = [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3]

from collections import Counter

c = Counter(lst)
min_cnt = min(c.values())
new_lst = list( zip(tokens, lst) )

while True:
    tmp = []
    should_break = True
    for t, i in new_lst:
        if c[i] > min_cnt:
            c[i] -= 1
            should_break = False
        else:
            tmp.append( (t, i) )

    new_lst = tmp

    if should_break:
        break

print([t for t, _ in new_lst])
```

Prints:

```
['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'l']
```

---

Other possible solution with `groupby`:

```
tokens = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','l']
lst    = [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3]

from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby, islice

c = Counter(lst)
min_cnt = min(c.values())

out = []
for v, g in groupby(sorted(enumerate(zip(tokens, lst)), key=lambda k: k[1][1]), lambda k: k[1][1]):
    out.extend(islice(g, 0, min_cnt))

print( [val for _, (val, _) in sorted(out, key=lambda k: k[0])] )
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another short solution:

```
import random
from itertools import chain
from operator import itemgetter
import toolz

tokens  = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','l']
classes = [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3]

groups = toolz.groupby(itemgetter(1), zip(tokens, classes))
max_size = len(min(groups.values(), key=len))
random_samples = chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x: random.sample(x, k=max_size), list(groups.values())))

chosen_tokens, corresponding_classes = list(zip(*random_samples))
```

or alternatively completely with `buildins` modules

```
import random
from itertools import chain, groupby, tee
from operator import itemgetter

tokens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'l']
classes = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]

groups_for_max_size, groups = tee(groupby(zip(tokens, classes), itemgetter(1)), 2)
max_size = len(min(groups_for_max_size, key = len))

random_samples = chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x: random.sample(list(x[1]), k = max_size), groups))
chosen_tokens, corresponding_classes = list(zip(*random_samples))
```

---

Edit: I think there is even a more shorter solution:

```
from itertools import chain, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

groups = (sorted(tokens, key=lambda x: random.random()) 
          for _, tokens in groupby(zip(tokens, classes), itemgetter(1)))
chosen_tokens, corresponding_classes = zip(*chain.from_iterable(zip(*groups)))
```

There just two steps: 1. make sure the lists per group are randomized (this happens magically in `sorted(tokens, key=lambda x: random.random())` because the sort key is always a random value).
2. It is also important to know that `zip` samples elements until the shortest generator is exhausted (which makes this solution so short). `zip(*groups)` is an iterator that retrieves triplets (since 3 classes) in each iteration. Because we shuffled the lists beforehand, they are thus sampled randomly. If we want again to separate tokens and classes we concatenate the triplets and unzip them again.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `Counter`:

```
import random
from collections import Counter

tokens  = np.array(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','l'])
classes = np.array([ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3])

def sampling(tokens, classes):
    dc = {}
    sol = []
    for i in range(len(classes)):
        if classes[i] in dc:
            dc[classes[i]].append(tokens[i])
        else:
            dc[classes[i]] = [tokens[i]]
    sample_counts = Counter(classes)
    min_sample = min(sample_counts.values())
    for i in dc:
        sol += (random.sample(dc[i],min_sample))
    return sol

print(sampling(tokens, classes))

>>> ['d', 'a', 'f', 'e', 'g', 'h']
```